# Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 has USB OTG (On The Go)?

Tags: hardware, samsung-galaxy-ace, usb-host-mode, usb-on-the-go

Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 supports USB OTG (On The Go)?

I've dedicated a long time to research, both in Google and on specialized sites (rich in Technical features), but I could not figure out if this device has this feature.

Here in Brazil this device is marketed as *Galaxy S II Duos TV*, much poorer in specific device technical features since it was only released for this local market. Therefore if I find out about the *Galaxy Ace 3*, brother machine, I think I find the answer.

Having to buy a device only know it's crazy, but I have real buying interest for being OTG valuable.

Answer (score 2):

phoned to samsung hotline today, they said no.